# How to prevent PhpStorm from breaking on ReflectionExceptions?

Tags: phpstorm

The following adding the conditions have not worked so far:

- `!(Exception instanceof ReflectionException)`
- `!(Exception instanceof \ReflectionException)`
- `!(this instanceof ReflectionException)`
- `!(this instanceof \ReflectionException)`
- `!anInstanceOf(ReflectionException)`
- `!anInstanceOf(\ReflectionException)`

It still always breaks when a ReflectionException is thrown.

[PhpStorm Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-properties)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no way, unfortunately.

A breakpoint condition is being sent to Xdebug within an `eval` command, so it has to be something that can actually be evaluated.

The `Exception` node in the PhpStorm's `Variables` pane, on the other hand, is received from Xdebug upon a `break` event once and can not be requested/evaluated further, so you can't put it into the condition.

So, it's either PhpStorm that should have an extra field in Exception Breakpoints that would check the `Exception` node contents, or Xdebug should have it possible to evaluate the exception somehow.

I'd say it's worth filing a feature request to us: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=WI

Comment: Created!  Thank you, Eugene!  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-61623